# Trigger outbrain widget on infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a infinite scroll plugin with a DOM jquery function triggering external functions such instagram, twitter and fb widgets in order to make them work on selector load. My question is, does anyone knows how the trigger outbrain's widgets?

https://widgets.outbrain.com/outbrain.js

Appreciate any help. Cheers.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  (function($) {
    $(document).on( 'name', function() {
        instgrm.Embeds.process();
        twttr.widgets.load();
        FB.XFBML.parse();
        OUTBRAIN?
    });
  })(jQuery);
});
```

Comment: Ok I got it. OBR.extern.researchWidget();

Comment: Excellent! `OBR.extern.researchWidget()` was exactly what I needed.